# Convert string to camel case with special character

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have string `test@test testing_test` and want to convert camelCase like (Test@Test Testing_Test)
Every first character of word after special character should be in camel case.
Could you please help me to write javascript function.

Comment: Hi, reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting an answer. Please note that providing complete implementations based on a list of requirements is not a goal of this community. Questions about requirements or objectives should demonstrate the **work or research you’ve done so far** and ask a specific question. You should edit your question to include what have you tried and where are you stuck. By the way, `java` and `javascript` are not the same, so please do not use both tags if not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to match the characters you want to modify. For example:

```
let input = 'test@test test_test';
let output = input.replaceAll(
  /(_|\b)\w/g, // match _ or a word boundary followed by a "word" character
  (x) => x.toLocaleUpperCase() // convert each found result to uppercase
);
```